# Dapper simple mapping

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, dapper

Table:

```
create table Documents 
   (Id int, 
    SomeText varchar(100), 
    CustomerId int, 
    CustomerName varchar(100)
   )

insert into Documents (Id, SomeText, CustomerId, CustomerName) 
   select 1, '1', 1, 'Name1' 
     union all
   select 2, '2', 2, 'Name2'
```

Classes:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
    public Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get all `Documents` with their `Customers` with Dapper? This gives me all documents, but the customer is null (of course):

```
connection.Query<Document>("select Id, SomeText, CustomerId, CustomerName from Documents")...
```

EDIT - similar, but more advanced mapping question: [Dapper intermediate mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223620/dapper-intermediate-mapping)

Comment: A big thanks for providing, in the question, the necessary SQL schema, c# classes, and your current code. It is much appreciated, and makes for a very well written question.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Very well said. +1'd this question just for this fact, so OP gets even more encouraged to participate in this community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example taken from [dapper project page](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) (see the Multi Mapping section):

```
var sql = 
@"select * from #Posts p 
left join #Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerId 
Order by p.Id";

var data = connection.Query<Post, User, Post>(sql, (post, user) => { post.Owner = user; return post;});
var post = data.First();

post.Content.IsEqualTo("Sams Post1");
post.Id.IsEqualTo(1);
post.Owner.Name.IsEqualTo("Sam");
post.Owner.Id.IsEqualTo(99);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great but I simplified my question too much - this is my real problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223620/dapper-intermediate-mapping :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var docs = connection.Query<Document, Customer, Document>(
    "select Id, SomeText, CustomerId as [Id], CustomerName as [Name] from Documents",
    (doc, cust) => { doc.Customer = cust; return doc; }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great but I simplified my question too much - this is my real problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223620/dapper-intermediate-mapping :)

Comment: I have similar classes and two table of database. I JOIN this two table but I'm getting this error: When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id