# How to get a nested list in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a list of results with a nested list.
I need the `fileds[3]` to have the fields of all the `Symbol` class.

My C# model is:

```
public class Watchlist
{
    public Watchlist(object[] fields)
    {
        WatchlistId = (int)fields[0];
        AccountId = (string)fields[1];
        Name = (string)fields[2];
        SymbolList = SetSymbolData(fields[3]);
    }

    public int WatchlistId { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Symbol> SymbolList { get; set; }
}

public class Symbol
{
    public Symbol() { }

    public Symbol(object[] fields)
    {
        Ticker = fields[0] == null ? "" : fields[0].ToString();
        Exchange = fields[1] == null ? "" : fields[1].ToString();
        Name = fields[2] == null ? "" : fields[2].ToString();
    }

    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Exchange { get; set; }
}
```

The current SQL I have is this:

```
SELECT w.Id, w.Account_id, w.Name, s.symbol, s.name, s.exchange FROM
(SELECT Id, Account_id, Name FROM Watchlists where Account_id = @AccountId) w
JOIN WatchlistSymbols ws ON w.Id = ws.WatchlistId
JOIN Symbols s ON s.id = ws.SymbolId
```

RESULT:

```
Id   Account_id    Name  symbol   name            exchange
----------- -----------------------------------------------------
26     123         TEST   AAA     Listed Funds     PACF
26     123         TEST  ACQRU    Independence     NQSC
26     123         TEST   ACTD    ArcLight         NQSC
```

But this returns a single row for each watchlist symbol combination.

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

A result set from a SQL database is always a table with a fixed number of columns on every row, you can't get "jagged" or "nested" results directly from SQL as a result set.

You have three options.

One is to [change SQL Server's output to JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and parse that json using something like the Newtonsoft nuget package.

Another is to read the result set and write your own nested loops in C# to process the rows.

A third way is to use an object relational mapper, and tell it how to parse the tabular result set. [Here's an example solution using Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985231/dapper-selecting-nested-objects)