# Dapper splitOn error

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to have dapper return `List<KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>>`

I have made what I believe to be the absolute simplest possible query to illustrate the issue:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
            return conn.Query<int, string, bool, KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>>("SELECT 1 AS 'SomeInt', 'A' AS 'SomeString', 'True' AS 'SomeBool'", (i, s, b) =>
                new KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>(
                    i,
                    new
                    {
                        TheString = s,
                        TheBool = b
                    }
                ), splitOn: "SomeString").AsList();
}
```

When I try to run this I get `System.ArgumentException: 'When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id`.

I think that I am specifying the `splitOn` parameter correctly as `SomeString` ... ?

I have looked at a number of other SO questions regarding this error including [Dapper Multi-mapping Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042618/dapper-multi-mapping-issue), [When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id", "splitOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168926/when-using-the-multi-mapping-apis-ensure-you-set-the-spliton-param-if-you-have-k), and [Correct use of Multimapping in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper/7478958), and if the answer is in one of those I can't find it.

I specifically tried to mirror what the answer here [Correct use of Multimapping in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper/7478958#7478958), but it doesn't work for me.

I did notice that in the vast majority of other examples, the code looks like `conn.Query<x, y, x>` (i.e. the return value is listed as the first value as well). I'm not sure if this matters or not, or even if I'm able to do what I want. I'm pretty new to Dapper.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you go into detail on why List<KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>> is the desired outcome?

Comment: @ParrishHusband What I really want is `List<KeyValuePair<int, Tuple<string, bool>>>`, but I want to name the string and the bool, not `item1` and `item2`. I am aware that I could create a class with a string and a bool and have dapper map to that class, but this is the only place in the whole code base where I would reference that class, so it seems ... excessive I guess. (This is in an API, so after I execute the query I send the results as JSON to a front-end website, and I don't want the front-end to have to deal with `item1` and `item2`.)

Comment: "this is the only place in the whole code base where I would reference that class".  Right now that may be true, but if requirements ever change down the road you're stuck trying to manipulate a complicated structure instead of just basic encapsulation.  Dapper's strength lies in wiring up your POCO classes easily and not needing to dig in the weeds as you are now.

Comment: You need a splitOn value for each of your int, string, bool objects, the final type is your return object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add the other fields in the `splitOn` value because each is a distinct class. Since each could be mapped to a separate POCO class, but in your case each is a distinct value.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    return conn
        .Query<int, string, string, KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>>(
            "SELECT 1 AS 'SomeInt', 'A' AS 'SomeString', 'True' AS 'SomeBool'",
            (i, s, b) =>
                new KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>(
                    i,
                    new
                    {
                        TheString = s,
                        TheBool = Convert.ToBoolean(b)
                    }),
            splitOn: "SomeInt,SomeString,SomeBool")
        .AsList();
}
```

Also I had to fix the boolean, since it was not converted correctly. Maybe in your case it's read from an actual database table and would work.

To illustrate the power of `splitOn`, take the following modification to the previous answer. This one splits the 3 values returned from the SQL query as 2 objects, the 1st into the `int` object and the 2nd and 3rd into a single `dynamic` object:

```
conn
    .Query<int, dynamic, KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>>(
        "SELECT 1 AS 'SomeInt', 'A' AS 'SomeString', 'True' AS 'SomeBoolean'",
        map: (i, d) => new KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>(i, new
        {
            TheString = d.SomeString, 
            TheBool = d.SomeBoolean
        }),
        splitOn: "SomeInt,SomeString")
   .AsList();
```

Comment: Yeah. I realized the boolean needed to be cast after posting the question. Thanks!