# C# Dapper Model not updating only one element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I seem to be having a problem with my model not updaing, but it seems there is only one aspect that.

I have the following setup

```
public class Stages
{
    public int ItemNumber {get; set;}   <-- seems to be updating correctly
    public string ItemName {get; set;}  <-- seems to be updating correctly
    public int ItemStage {get; set;}    <-- always results in 0
}

public interface IStageRepository
{
    List<Stages> GetAll();
}

public class StageRepository : IStageRepository
{
    private IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StagesConnection"].ConnectionString);

    public List<Stages> GetAll()
    {
        return this.db.Query<Stages>("SELECT * FROM Stages_vw").ToList();
    }
}
```

Under my HomeController I have the following

```
IStageRepository stagesRepo = new StageRepository();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return (stagesRepo.GetAll());
}
```

Here is the schema of the view

```
TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_DEFAULT
WebServices     dbo             Stages_vw   ItemNumber  NULL
WebServices     dbo             Stages_vw   ItemName    NULL
WebServices     dbo             Stages_vw   Stage       NULL
```

If I do a "SELECT * FROM Stages_vw" in SSMS the results are correct

I have stumbled across these posts but I am feeling a little confused any help would be greatly appreciated

**ANSWER per @chipples**

This was due to a column name in the view not matching

[dapper-simple-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170882/dapper-simple-mapping)

[dapper-intermediate-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223620/dapper-intermediate-mapping)

[Dapper Documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

Comment: Ty explicitly naming the selected fields instead of `select *`

Comment: What is the schema of your table Stages_vw?

Comment: @markpsmith same result when specifying `select ItemName, ItemNumber, ItemStage`

Comment: @Steve I have updated the original post with schema

Comment: I may be missing something but I can't see your db schema - does the database column name definitely match the property name in the model?

Comment: @chipples I hadn't saved the schema yet, also that was the problem, the column was named Stage in the view once I updated to ItemStage it's now displaying the correct information thanks, figured it was something simple I missed

Comment: @chipples is correct - the column is displayed as Stage and the object property is called ItemStage. They must be identically named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, the problem is that the names on your model and in your database do no match (ItemStage in the model, Stage in the DB). Dapper requires the names to match in order to map automatically. You should either rename the property on your model to Stage, or use an alias in your SQL ("SELECT Stage AS ItemStage...").